# how to localize and and or in jqgrid advanced search window

Tags: jqgrid, localization

By clicking search button in toolbar, advanced search window is opened.
In first row it contains combobox with selections AND and OR

How to replace those words with words in other language in this window ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with localization is the bug in [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.formedit.js#L149-166) where `jqFilter` method will be called by `searchGrid` method. The method `jqFilter` supports [groupOps](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.filter.js#L75) option which are already set in many localization files `grid.locale-XX.js`, but the `jqFilter` method will be called *without* setting of the option.

To fix the problem one should just add

```js
groupOps: p.groupOps,
```

to the list of options used in the call of `jqFilter` method. You can search for the text `).jqFilter({` in the `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` or in the `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` to find the corresponding place. In `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` of jqGrid 4.3.1 the `p` is renamed to `f` so one have to use `groupOps:f.groupOps`.

How you can see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalizedGroupOps.htm) the grouping operation in the Advanced Searching dialog will be localized after applying the fix:

[image]

If your localized version of `grid.locale-XX.js` don't contains the texts for AND and OR operation you can set there manually

```js
$.jgrid.search.groupOps = [
    {op: "My And", text: "my AND operation"},
    {op: "My Or", text: "my OR operation"}
];
```

see [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalizedGroupOps1.htm):

[image]

Without the described bug fix you can follow my suggestion from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6994487/315935) on the close question.

**UPDATED**: I posted [the corresponding bug](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/localized-and-and-or-grouping-operation-dont-used-in-advanced-search-dialog/#p26111) report to trirand. I hope that the fix will be included in the main code of jqGrid.

**UPDATED 2**: The bug fix is already included in [the main code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/) of the jqgrid (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/c14e5aadb8dcf75bda972cb2b6da864225c59a19#L0R163)).