# jqGrid add custom search operator (ops object)

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid

how can I add search operators without intervening directly in the file `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`?

example:

```js
ops: [
    {"name": "eq", "description": "equal", "operator": "="},
    {"name": "ne", "description": "not equal", "operator": "<>"},
    {"name": "lt", "description": "less", "operator": "<"},
    {"name": "the", "description": "less or equal", "operator": "<="},
    {"name": "gt", "description": "greater", "operator": ">"},
    {"name": "ge", "description": "greater or equal", "operator": "> ="},
    {"name": "bw", "description": "begins with", "operator": "LIKE"},
    {"name": "bn", "description": "does not begin with", "operator": "NOT LIKE"},
    {"name": "in", "description": "in", "operator": "IN"},
    {"name": "ni", "description": "not in", "operator": "NOT IN"},
    {"name": "ew", "description": "ends with", "operator": "LIKE"},
    {"name": "en", "description": "does not end with", "operator": "NOT LIKE"},
    {"name": "cn", "description": "contains", "operator": "LIKE"},
    {"name": "nc", "description": "Does not contain", "operator": "NOT LIKE"},
    {"name": "noo", "description": "is null", "operator": "IS NULL"},
    {"name": "nn", "description": "is not null", "operator": "IS NOT NULL"},
    {"name": "xx", "description": "xxx", "operator": "CUSTOM"} ]
```

this change works correctly, but you can do it with an external files?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should understand that adding custom searching operator is not follow the *implementation* of the operator. I suppose that you have *server side implementation* of the searching. In the case extending of searching operation is mostly simple.

The internal structure `ops` will be changed in the next version of jqGrid. So I recommend you just modify `<select>` options on the fly inside of `afterRedraw`. Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9724111/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9078572/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6994487/315935) for the corresponding code examples. In your case you can use

```js
afterRedraw: function () {
    $(this).find("table.group td.operators>select.selectopts")
        .append("<option value='xx'>xxx</option>");
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomSearchingOperation.htm) uses the above `afterRedraw` and displays

[image]

The demo uses *local* `datatype`, so the searching with the operation is not work of cause, but `postData` parameters will be set corresponds to the chosen operation.